# How to link and route two ngFor loops with each other in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ngfor

I am trying to build a web-page using angular. I need to connect only data's of 2nd ngFor loop that are correlated to 1st ngFor loop.

HTML CODE

```
<div *ngFor="let year of years">
    <h2> {{year}} </h2>   // For displaying the year row
    </div>


<div *ngFor="let month of months">
    <h4> {{month}}</h4> // For displaying the month row
    </div>


//Now i need to print all the data respect to each month and data.

year = ['2019','2018','2017','2016']

month = ['jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul', 'aug','sep','oct','nov','dec']

Output should be like
```

2019 2018 2017 2016

jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec

(all data respect to each month and year should be present as shown)

2019

8th aug - data

5th aug - data

28th june - data

5 jan - data

2018

29th dec - data

21 dec - data

18 oct - data

(and so on...)

and if we click on any of the year, the page will scroll to that year.
there may be all 12 months data for that year or may be only some months.
so suppose if we click 2018 , then page will scroll to 2018 and then "if" i click on "oct" if there is a data for 2018 oct then it will scroll there else nothing will happen. it cant scroll to oct of any other year.

```
The structure of data is like 

year -- date -- data
2019 -- 8th aug -- data
2019 -- 5th aug -- data
```

Comment: please provide the code, which you have tried so far.. for better understanding of your requirement... ?

Comment: i am new in angular, so dont know, how to do it. I tried reading data binding, but was unable to know how to use it  in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach based on what you have provided in your description. You just need to filter the second list based on the first one's selected item. [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdyqps)

```js
import {
  Component
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  alphaBet: string;
  english = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

  name = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4',
    'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4',
    'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4',
    'd1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4',
    'e1', 'e2', 'e3', 'e4',
    'f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4'
  ];

  scrollToNames(val) {
    const elems = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('names'));
    const macthes = elems.filter((item) => {
      return item.innerHTML.includes(val);
    });
    macthes[0].scrollIntoView();
  }
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let alphabets of english">
  <h2 (click)="scrollToNames(alphabets)"> {{alphabets}} </h2>
</div>


<div *ngFor="let names of name">
  <h4 class="names"> {{names}}</h4>
</div>
```

Also you can use pipes to filter the second list based on the selection. This is just one way demonstrated above;

Hope this helps :)

Comment: the method works fine, but here i just gave an example of the contact list, so the startswith that you have used, i can't use that as the names may have some salutation in start like Mr. or Mrs. so the final name would be  "Mr. e1" but it should also come in the e section.

I will update the question.

Comment: @AchalUtkarsh in that case you just need to use a different function.. `includes` might work for you.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: The last part of my problem is still there, the process you proposed is only filtering according to the part, but i want all the details to be shown and if i click on some the page will just scroll down to that specific section.

Comment: @AchalUtkarsh updated the code.. In this case just add class to all the elements of the second list and then use that to get the elements and filter them out based on the selection.. Above code and Demo link both updated.. Hope this will solve your problem..

Comment: this works for the name scenario as we can give new class to everyone, I have added one more scenario with some extra data, can you please help me with that?

Comment: Please dont mind but the question is totally different from your intial query you should have posted this as a different question..

Comment: So for this scenario the same solution will work you just need add class to years now and then perform a similar filter like names and that will solve your problem.. For items that belong to 2018 add a class names `year-2018` and then use this to filter

Comment: i will try this solution.

Comment: i am sorry for the change of question, but after working on it, it started getting more complex, thats why so many edits .

Answer (score 0):

you can write second loop like below.

**#1**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let names of name">
   <div *ngIf="names.startsWith(selectedAlphabets)">
     <h4> {{names}}</h4>
   </div>
</ng-container>
```

though this is not good approach as everytime you change selectedAlphabets and according to that it will have to iterate whole name list again.
if you can change you names list to map of alphabet character to list of name then it will be more faster because it can directly pick list of selected alphabet as below.

**#2**

```
    import {
      Component
    } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

      alphaBet: string;
      english = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

      name = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4',
        'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4',
        'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4',
        'd1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4',
        'e1', 'e2', 'e3', 'e4',
        'f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4'
      ];

      nameMap = new Map<string, string[]>();

      public ngOnInit(){
          this.generateNameMap();
      }

      generateNameMap() {
        for (const item of this.name) {
            if (!this.nameMap.get(item.charAt(0))) {
                this.nameMap.set(item.charAt(0), []);
            }

            this.nameMap.get(item.charAt(0)).push(item);
        }
      }


      /* other code */
    }
```

and change second for loop html part like this

```
<div *ngFor="let names of nameMap.get(selectedAlphabets)">
  <h4> {{names}}</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: i did not understand this line 'So when you click "a" it will divert to "amitabh" , same with others "b" to "Shahrukh", "c" to "salman" and so on'.
what is logic for mapping b to Shahrukh and c to Salman? 
does it mean, you want to display all names that contain selected character ?

Comment: check the another scenario, i hope you will get it then.   ,, I basically gave a theme using "a","b","c" that there are some data that they are diverting to, it was not same as 'a','b','c'.

Comment: you missed the "month" line , that first click year ,let us suppose 2017 then if we click month april, then it should go to april of 2017, and u added all the months, what if the data of some months are not there, check the scenario again.

Comment: that is just an example. Though i have updated it  as per your comment. You can think more based on your scenario and handle month not there case.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngFor="let alphabets of english">
    <h2 (click)=scrollToLetter(alphabets)> {{alphabets}} </h2>
    </div>


<div *ngFor="let names of name">
    <h4 id="{{names}}">{{names}}</h4>
    </div>
```

And then in your TypeScript:

```
public scrollToLetter(letter) {
  console.log(`scrolling to ${letter}`);
  var id = this.name.find(function(element) {
      return element.toLowerCase().startsWith(letter);
  });
  if (id) {
      let el = document.getElementById(id);
      el.scrollIntoView();
  }
}
```

Remember to apply appropriate styling to the scrollable list, eg:

```
  height: 50px;
  max-height:50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
```